# Find the $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ of $\{x_{n}\}$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, supremum-and-infimum, limsup-and-liminf

Compute using their definition the $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ of $\{x_{n}\}$ with $x_n:= y_1 + y_2 + \dotsc + y_n$

$y_n$ := \begin{cases}
0 & \text{if } n =3p \\
1  & \text{if } n = 3p+1\\
-1  & \text{if } n= 3p+2
\end{cases}
Definitions:

$\limsup{x_n} = \lim{y_n}$ with $\{y_{n}\} := \{\sup{x_m},m \geq n\}$

$\liminf{x_n} = \lim{z_n}$ with $\{z_{n}\} := \{\inf{x_m}, m \geq n\}$

In the same exercise we were asked to compute the $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ of $\{x_{n}\}$ with $x_n:= (-1)^n(2-\frac{1}{n})$. What I did for the $\limsup$ was show that the subsequences $y_{2p}$ and $y_{2p+1}$ such that $y_{2p}= \sup\{2-\frac{1}{2p},-2+\frac{1}{2p+1},\dotsc\}$ and $y_{2p+1}= \sup\{-2+\frac{1}{2p+1},2-\frac{1}{2p+2},\dotsc\}$ both converge to 2 so that $\limsup{x_n} = 2$. Using the same method, I showed that $\liminf{x_n} = -2$.

How do I find the $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ of $\{x_{n}\}$ described above?

Comment: Start by computing $x_n$ for the first several values of $n$; you should be able to write down a general formula (possibly with multiple cases).

Comment: Start by finding limit of subsequences of $x_n$. Note that there are 3 types of sequences of x viz. $\{x_{3p+1}\},\{x_{3p}\},\{x_{3p+2}\}$. Then limsup $x_n$= supremum of limits of subsequences.